# Add class to DIV based on id of object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add a class to a div based on the id of a field in a object. So far my code is not working for some reason?

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of cards">
   <div class="card event-card mb-3">
      <div
         class="card-body"
         [ngClass]="{
         'card-main': id === '1',
         'card-main2': id === '2'
         }"
         >
         <p class="card-title">{{ item.title }}</p>
         {{ item.date }}, {{ item.time }}
         {{ item.id }}
      </div>
   </div>
</ng-container>



public cards = [
    {
      title: "Example title",
      date: "Jan 25, 2025",
      time: "11:22am",
      typeEvent: "Concert",
      id: "1"
    },
    {
      title: "Example title",
      date: "Feb 27, 2029",
      time: "14:22pm",
      typeEvent: "Show",
      id: "2"
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `item.id` instead of just `id` for the comparison.